# A library/service that loads *all* modernizr webshims/polyfills at once?

Tags: modernizr, polyfills, webshim

I'm looking to be able to use, in perhaps a couple lines of code, an external call to load every single webshim for a browser.

I understand that this would load the browser with dozens of *useless* shims.  For quick development, this is fine for a short period (really!).  As my site is ready to launch and I've figured out which shims need to stay, I'd want to be able to pass a whitelist and/or blacklist of features, modernizr style, so that I wouldn't be using unneeded shims.

What I'm hoping to avoid is basically having to compare various shims, and instead have a single service that loads the latest version of the best of breed.  I'd also want it to consolidate the js files that are downloaded.

In short a "modernize_all", which shims everything by default, for instance during a quick web hack meetup or when time is limited.  Also can be passed only the specific tests to modernize at a later time to save browser downloads & memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None exist, however the current moderizr github repo has a [list of polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/lib/polyfills.json). It would be trivial to build a dev version of modernizr, download all of the linked shims, and then set up a bunch of yepnopes

Answer (score 1):

The Webshim JSFiddle examples all call the Git JS directly: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js. 
I have tried this on CodePen myself for experiment purposes and it works fine polyfilling all components you specify.
Be sure to include jQuery and Modernizer too.